# Infrequent Handler.post's cause huge frame drops and crashes

Tags: android, android-networking, android-handler, android-threading

I have a simple thread listening to UDP broadcasts to discover devices on my network.  Whenever it receives a broadcast, it posts a `Runnable` to a `Handler` on the UI thread to add the device's IP to an `ArrayList`.  At most, it receives packets once every 2 seconds.  I've verified that the posts only happen every 2 seconds.

My app also has a few fragments.  Whenever I switch using `NavController.navigate()` between fragments I get anywhere from 100-400 frame drops and ANRs.  When I disable the thread, or even just disable searching for duplicates and adding the device to the `ArrayList`, the frame drops go away, but the searching and adding take less than 1ms (according to debug prints).

I've read a bunch of other thread about problems with `Handlers`, but none of them helped.  Any idea why my posts are causing so many frame drops?

Here's the run method of the Thread:

```
public void run(){
            try {
                DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(DISCOVERY_PORT);
                ds.setSoTimeout(500);
                ds.setBroadcast(true);
                byte[] rxBuffer = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(rxBuffer,rxBuffer.length);

                while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        ds.receive(dp);

                        String msg = new String(rxBuffer, 0, dp.getLength());
                        dp.setLength(rxBuffer.length);
                        callbackH.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                addGeophone(dp.getAddress().toString(),Integer.parseInt(msg));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                ds.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And the addGeophone function that gets posted to the UI thread:

```
    private static void addGeophone(String ipAddress, int id){
        boolean geophoneFound = false;
        Geophone g;
        //REMOVE BELOW HERE AND EVERYTHING SPEEDS UP.
        for (int i = 0; i < geophones.size(); i++){
            g = geophones.get(i);
            if (g.id == id){
                geophoneFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (!geophoneFound) {
            geophones.add(new Geophone(ipAddress, id));
       }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong from the code you posted. How big is your geophones list? If it is large it might help to create a HashMap (or SparseArray) and index it by the ID.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing, there's only like 4 elements in it, but it's still super slow..

Comment: Just another guess, maybe it's the constructor `new Geophone` that's slow? What is being done in that constructor?

Comment: That one should be fast.  Right now the `Geophone` class is jut a `String`, an `int` and the constructor The constructor just assigns values to them.  The whole `addGeophone` function takes almost no time at all, but only when it actually runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `DatagramPacket.getAddress()` takes a really long time if it's executed from another thread. When I moved the `getAddress` call to the poster thread, everything sped up.

```
public void run(){
            try {
                DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(DISCOVERY_PORT);
                ds.setSoTimeout(500);
                ds.setBroadcast(true);
                byte[] rxBuffer = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(rxBuffer,rxBuffer.length);
                while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        ds.receive(dp);

                        String msg = new String(rxBuffer, 0, dp.getLength());
                        dp.setLength(rxBuffer.length);
                        String ipAddress = dp.getAddress().toString();
                        callbackH.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                addGeophone(ipAddress,Integer.parseInt(msg));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                ds.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```